# Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found after install

Tags: joomla, php, install

Just did a clean install of Joomla 4.23 with Civi 5.54.0 running on PhP 8.0 via xampp. Install went fine including databasee upgrade but can't get to CiviCRM dashboard. Error message is
'Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found" and button sends me back to Joomla dashboard.
My understanding is that Joomla 4.x works with Civi 5.54 and both are compatible with PhP 8.0. Am I missing a compatibility issue? What else could it be?
Thanks,
Kate

Answer (score 2):

You need php `intl` enabled. See https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#required-for-civicrm-core.